# How do I install the DisplayLink driver for Ubuntu on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, display, driver

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2 with Raspbian Stretch 9.1 as an OS. I have the USB graphics adapter Kensington K33907. How can I proceed to install the DisplayLink driver for Ubuntu on Raspbian? I have tried the script from GitHub:

https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian

But it doesn't work. It asks me that it has to install Linux-header-4.9.59-v7+ because it doesn't see it. I say ok. But it doesn't work. Installation failed. Aborting

```
--------------------------- displaylink-debian ----------------------------

DisplayLink driver installer for Debian based Linux distributions:

* Debian GNU/Linux
* Ubuntu
* Elementary OS
* Linux Mint
* Kali Linux

Options:

[I]nstall
[U]ninstall
[R]e-install
[Q]uit

Select a key: [i/u/r/q]: i

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Checking dependencies

unzip is installed
linux-headers-4.9.59-v7+ not found! Install? [Y/n] y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.59-v7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.59-v7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.59-v7'
linux-headers-4.9.59-v7+ installation failed.  Aborting.
pi@raspberrypi-arnold:~/Downloads/displaylink-debian-master $ uname -r
4.9.59-v7+
```

When I make the command:

```
$ uname -a

Linux raspberrypi-arnold 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

So have you a solution to install the displaylink driver for Ubuntu to a Raspbian?

Answer (score 1):

Your specific error is because the Raspberry Pi kernel header package doesn't follow the standard naming scheme. The displaylink-debian script needs to be edited to change all instances of `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` so that the Pi's kernel headers are installed properly.

If the script still doesn't work, there may be other similar dependency names to check. You can also consult https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1883065-using-arm-binaries-on-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi for more information specific to installing the DisplayLink drivers on a Pi.

Edit: specifically this line in displaylink-debian.sh, change

deps=(unzip linux-headers-$(uname -r) to
deps=(unzip raspberrypi-kernel-headers